# How do I get NULL into a MySQL integer column with PHP/MySQLi?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, null, integer

I'm passing values into a PHP page through the URL and using them in queries with MySQLi.  The problem is that an empty string gets converted to zero for an integer column, when in fact it needs to be NULL.

How do I get NULL into an integer column with PHP/MySQLi, from a param passed in the URL?

Update:
Here's an example of how I'd use the incoming parameter and a prepared statement to do the insert.  The one I need to be NULL on the DB is $specialtyType.

```
function InsertItem($itemID, $ownerID, $specialtyType)
{
    $this->insertItemStmt->bind_param("ssi", $itemID, $ownerID, $specialtyType);
    $this->insertItemStmt->execute();
```

If I add Jason's suggested line before the bind_param (setting up an intermediate variable and using it in the bind_param instead of $specialty_type), it winds up containing 0 after the execute().

Comment: Did you try `$specialtyType = null`?

Comment: I ended up rewriting it so that the parameter isn't passed to the server at all if it should be null, but I suspect setting it to NULL (without quotes) would indeed have worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$int_value = empty($_GET['int_value']) ? NULL : (int)$_GET['int_value'];
```

Use `$int_value` for the column in your `INSERT`.

Comment: Thanks, Jason. Unfortunately, this didn't work. I verified that the incoming string was empty and converted to "NULL" with your statement. I used the converted string in the bind_param statement, but the database still complained about the constraint violation. But if I execute an SQL INSERT statement with NULL for the column's value, it works fine.

Comment: Wow, that is one hairy expression! I think the lack of parens has caused the default operator precedence to defeat what you're trying to accomplish. I would rewrite this as:

`$int_value = strlen($_GET['int_value']) ? ((int)$_GET['int_value']) : 'NULL';`

Comment: @Oscar, so `INSERT` works but the `bind_param` doesn't. Please post that code. @kmoser, your rewrite is not a logical equivalent, as it would allow a space to be saved as zero not NULL.

Comment: I updated my post with some code.  For now I've worked around this by changing the client code to omit the parameter from the URL altogether when it's supposed to be null.  Then the $_GET['specialtyType'] retrieves nothing and sends it into the function above, and the DB column winds up NULL as intended.  Jason, is it possible that your line should not have quotes around the "NULL"?

Comment: I'm accepting this answer after removing the quotes around NULL.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The question is not how to send NULL to MySQL via mysqli, but rather how to get NULL value from the GET parameters.

I would suggest two ways. Either use `filter_input()` which is a really handy function or provide null as a default value if no value was passed in the URL query.

```
$id = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, FILTER_NULL_ON_FAILURE);
// or
$id = empty($_GET['id']) ? null : (int) $_GET['id'];

// If no value was presented in GET then $id will be passed as NULL
$stmt->bind_param('s', $id);
```

In my opinion `filter_input()` provides more correct outcome. See this comparison:

```
| $_GET['id']   | filter_input | Cast to int |
|---------------|--------------|-------------|
| Inexistent    | false        | NULL        |
|               | NULL         | NULL        |
| <white space> | NULL         | 0           |
| 0             | 0            | NULL        |
| 42            | 42           | 42          |
| 42.333        | NULL         | 42          |
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at your database schema to see if the column in question even allows for null values. If the column does not allow nulls, than it will use the default value for the field when you try to put in a null value… which is usually zero for integer fields.

Comment: It allows nulls.  This is a foreign key, which must either be null or a valid value from another table.  Otherwise, it's a constraint violation.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and just changed the relevant DB columns from INT to VARCHAR. Empty values are now stored as NULL and a 0 is a 0. Even deleting the 0 in PHP MyAdmin would see a '0' pop back up, so I guess INT equates empty with zero and VARCHAR doesn't.

Answer (score -2):

For MySQLi, you can't pass a constant like NULL or 0 or even "NULL" as a bind_param() argument.

Everything passed must be a reference type.  It's a stupid limitation, I know.

But working around it is easy.  Just create a throw-away variable.  In a project I have been working on, I needed insert some data to a BLOB field.  Unfortunately, MySQLi doesn't let you ***bind*** binary data if it's longer than a certain length.  You have to ***bind*** NULL and then follow-up with sending the binary info via **send_long_data()**.

But, again, you cannot bind a constant like NULL, so in the example, look where I used the variable **$Dummy**.

```
$InfoToInsert = array
(
    'a number' => 9000,
    'a double' => 9000.0,
    'a string' => 'Hello World',
    'a blob' => gzdeflate('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed')
);
$Stmnt =
(
    'INSERT INTO _mytable '.
        '(_myintcol, _mydoublecol _mystringcol, _myblobcol) '.
    'VALUES '.
        '(?, ?, ?, ?)'
);
if(!$PreparedStmnt = $Conn->prepare($Stmnt))
{
    $OutputError = 'Failure preparing statement: '.my_SanitizeHtml($Conn->error).'<br /><br />Full query:<br />'.$Stmnt;
    $Conn->rollback();
    $Conn->close();
    return(false);
}
$Dummy = null;
$PreparedStmnt->bind_param
(
    'idsb',                         // Possible types:
                                    //     i for Integer
                                    //     d for Double
                                    //     s for String
                                    //     b for BLOB

    $InfoToInsert['a number'],      // _myintcol
    $InfoToInsert['a double'],      // _mydoublecol
    $InfoToInsert['a string'],      // _mystringcol
    $Dummy                          // _myblobcol
);
$PreparedStmnt->send_long_data(3, $InfoToInsert['a blob']); // 3 because it's the 4th parameter (-1 for zero-based)
if(!$PreparedStmnt->execute())
{
    $OutputError = 'Failure inserting report: '.my_SanitizeHtml($Conn->error);
    $PreparedStmnt->close();
    $Conn->rollback();
    $Conn->close();
    return(false);
}
$PreparedStmnt->close();
```